# How to loop through a dictionary with the class instances?

Tags: python

I am a intern and try to implement a dictionary class. I need to loop  and print the objects from the class.
My code is:

```
class Shop:
    def __init__(self,prodid, prodname, prodtype, prodrating):
        self.prodid = prodid
        self.prodname = prodname
        self.prodtype = prodtype
        self.prodrating = prodrating

b1 = Shop("ID1", "My-Bot1", "Fashion1", 5)
b2 = Shop("ID2", "My-Bot2", "Fashion2", 6)
b3 = Shop("ID3", "My-Bot3", "Fashion3", 7)

b4 = Shop("ID4", "My-Bot2", "new born", 6)
b5 = Shop("ID5", "My-Bot3", "newborn", 7)

myDict = {}
myDict["clothing"] =  [b1,b2,b3]
myDict["infant"] =  [b4,b5]

for items in myDict.items():
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

I am not able to loop through the class instances and print the values.

Comment: Try printing the value of `items` in each iteration of the loop and you will see what is wrong. Apart from that, the indentation of the code need to be fixed to be able to understand the code and in addition it is not clear what "not able to loop through the class instances" mean. Do you get an error? In that case what error? Does it produce the wrong result? In that case, what did it produce? What did you expect?

Comment: what does the debugger tell you, You will be exhausted after the internship

Comment: You need to specify _which_ list in your dictionary you want to iterate over — e.g. `for items in myDict["clothing"]:`.

Comment: I am able to do for item in myDict.items():
    for val in myDict[item[0]]:
        print(val.prodid)
        print(val.prodname)
        print(val.prodtype)
        print(val.prodrating)

Comment: I have posted an answer below, hope it helps, but for future reference always post whatever output or traceback you get from the console with you question when possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just print out the objects (which, I suppose you will be wanting to implement a `__repr__` method) then you can just do this:

```
for shops in myDict.values():
    for shop in shops:
        print(shop)
```

Note that if you are using `dict.items()` it will return tuples of `(key, value)` so you would need to do `for key, items in myDict.items()` for your original example.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is how you are looping through the dictionary. The keyword `in` for a `dict` means *"give me the keys in order"* and then to get the content you will need to reference the dictionary with that key. Note that this is not the case on a list or tuple, on those it will give you the items that contains and to a `str` it means *"it contains the matching str"* (like in `"hu" in huhohihe`).

```
clothing_data = {
    "ID1": ["My-Bot1", "Fashion1", 5],
    "ID2": ["My-Bot2", "Fashion2", 6],
    "ID3": ["My-Bot3", "Fashion3", 7]
}

infant_data = {
    "ID4": ["My-Bot2", "new born", 6],
    "ID5": ["My-Bot3", "newborn", 7]
}

class Shop:
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Item id -> {0}, Name -> {1}'.format(
            self.prodid, self.prodname
        )

    def __init__(self, prodid, prodname, prodtype, prodrating):
        self.prodid = prodid
        self.prodname = prodname
        self.prodtype = prodtype
        self.prodrating = prodrating

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shop_data = {
        'clothing': [],
        'infant': []
    }

    for item in clothing_data:
        shop_data['clothing'].append(
            Shop(item, *clothing_data[item])
        )

    for item in infant_data:
        shop_data['infant'].append(
            Shop(item, *infant_data[item])
        )

    for c in shop_data:
        for i in shop_data[c]:
            print(i)
```